# How to combine vertex groups and texture as density map in geometry nodes?

Tags: vertex-groups, geometry-nodes

I would like to add, point density to be affected by weight painted vertex group as well as a texture (for instance cloud texture).

I can use vertex group as density influencer on point distribute node by writing the name of the vertex group on density parameter (ground.camPosition) as above:
[image]
I can use texture with attribute texture sample node:
[image]

However, I cannot combine them how can I combine vertex group and texture for combined density maps on geometry nodes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Blender 3.1 (GN-Fields) ...

- Create this node tree

[image]

- *Weight Paint* something ... it will automatically generates *Vertex Group* by default named *Group*

[image]

- With **Group Input** node selected go to *Modifier Properties* and next to the *Value* click on "spreadsheet" icon and choose your vertex group (here named *Group*) or type it into the field.

[image]

So ... in this case is texture mixed with vertex weight by *Math* node

Note: If you have difficulties to set vertex group attribute in modifier ... go to *Geometry nodes editor > Side panel* <kbd>N</kbd> ... there should by set type **Float** (it happens when plugged *Math* value) ... if there is something else switch to *Float* (*Vector* worked too).

Comment: Thank you very much! Extensively answering my question and well documented answer, I appreciate your effort. :)

Comment: Great if helpful .. it was a lesson for me ... so I marked the "dark"corners that wasn't much intuitive or new for me :)